# Asp.net web api controller long querystring returns BadRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an Asp.net web api with one method that receive a crypted string with variable length, my problem is it string some times could take a length near 5000.

When that method receive a string under 1930 length it process everything ok, but for lengths over 1929  returns

**404 Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'**

I changed method GET to POST but problem persists.

I changed filter options on server to very very long limits, but problem persists

This is my controller:

```
public class LicencingManagerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(nameof(SaveCustomer2))]
    public string SaveCustomer2(string custInfo)
    {
        return $"ItsOk = {custInfo}";
    }
}
```

Actually I made calls to controller using autogenerated c# client by AutoRest 2.0.483.

I tried hand building PostAsync Request using HttpClient but nothing works.

```
string custInfo = "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";

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("custInfo", custInfo)
    };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
var client = new HttpClient();

// call sync
var response = client.PostAsync($"{Modelos.Shared.HttpsServicesReference.Licencing}/LicencingAPI/SaveCustomer2", content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
}
```

What is the right way to process this controller call?

There is another approach to perform this ?

Comment: if using POST then content needs to be in the BODY of the request not the query string

Comment: @Nkosi Hi, maybe a sample ?

Comment: I would also suggest you ensure you are calling the correct URL. How did you configure routing?

Comment: @Nkosi Totally sure url is ok, because it works with strings up to 1929 lenght

Comment: I only mentioned checking the URL because you referred to a 404 message which is a NOT FOUND status response

Comment: Very tks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create model to hold data

```
public class Customer {
    public string CustumerInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Update API to expect model in body of request

```
public class LicencingManagerController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(nameof(SaveCustomer2))]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomer2([FromBody]Customer model) {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var custInfo = model.CustumerInfo;
        return Ok($"ItsOk = {custInfo}");
    }
}
```

Post content to API in body of the request like you did before

```
string custInfo = "H4sIAAAAAAAEAA...";
string url = $"{Modelos.Shared.HttpsServicesReference.Licencing}/LicencingAPI/SaveCustomer2";
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CustumerInfo", custInfo)
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

}
```

Comment: [FromBody] Do the magic !!!. Very very tks for your help. Something to learn every day !!! Tks for teach me.